# Angular 2 ngModel implementation

Tags: angular

I use this base class to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface and I extend it in each component, what I noticed is that if I put a break point in `get value()` and I have a view binding to this value, angular triggers this function continuous, is this the expected behavior ? Should I be concerned about this ?

```
import { ControlValueAccessor } from "@angular/forms";

export class BaseValueAccessor<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {

    public disabled: boolean;
    public valueRef: T;
    private elementValue: T;

    get value(): T {
        return this.elementValue;
    }


    set value(value: T) {
        if (value === this.elementValue) {
            return;
        }

        this.setValue(value);
        this._onChangeCallback(this.elementValue);
        this._onTouchedCallback();
        console.log('base-value-accessor trigger change');
    }

    writeValue(obj: T): void {
        this.setValue(obj);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (_: T) => {}): void {
        this._onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
        this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    markAsTouched() {
        this._onTouchedCallback();
    }

    private setValue(value: T) {
        this.elementValue = value;
        this.valueRef = this.elementValue;
    }

    private _onChangeCallback(_: T) {
    }

    private _onTouchedCallback() {
    } 
}
```

> This is the html for type ahead component

```
<md-input-container cdk-overlay-origin
                    [color]="color || 'primary'"
                    #origin="cdkOverlayOrigin"
                    #trigger>
    <input mdInput
           #firstInputHtmlRef
           [placeholder]="placeholder"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [(ngModel)]="value"
           (focusin)="onElementFocus($event)"
           (keydown)="onTypeAheadKeyDown($event)"
           (keyup)="onInputValueChange($event?.target?.value || '')"/>
    <span *ngIf="!disabled && !panelOpen"
          mdSuffix
          class="type-ahead-icon"
          [class.is-disabled]="disabled">
        <md-icon [style.visibility]="value && value.length > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
                 [color]="color || 'primary'"
                 (click)="onClearValue($event)">
            clear
        </md-icon>
        <md-icon [style.visibility]="icon ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
                 [color]="color || 'primary'"
                 (click)="showLookupWithSearch($event)">
            {{icon}}
        </md-icon>
    </span>
</md-input-container>
<ng-template cdk-connected-overlay
             [origin]="origin"
             [open]="panelOpen"
             hasBackdrop
             backdropClass="cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop"
             [positions]="panelPositionRelativeToTrigger"
             [minWidth]="triggerWidth"
             [offsetY]="0"
             (backdropClick)="closePane()">
    <!--The offsetY is set manually-->
    <div *ngIf="useCustomBackdrop"
         class="cay-backdrop-cover"
         (click)="closePane($event)">
    </div>
    <blu-type-ahead-selection-list #typeAheadListHtmlRef
                                   [class.has-input]="showSearchInsideLookup"
                                   [maxHeight]="innerComponentHeight"
                                   [maxWidth]="triggerWidth"
                                   [showList]="!typeAheadMessage"
                                   [items]="itemsList"
                                   [listItemClass]="listItemClass"
                                   [valueField]="trackByProperty"
                                   [selectedValue]="value"
                                   [showProperties]="visibleProperties"
                                   (onScrollDown)="onScrollDown($event)"
                                   (onSelect)="onSelectionChange($event)">
        <md-input-container *ngIf="showSearchInsideLookup"
                            class="lookup-inside-nav-list"
                            [color]="color || 'primary'">
            <input mdInput
                   #secondInputHtmlRef
                   [disabled]="disabled"
                   (click)="onTypeAheadLookupClick($event)"
                   [(ngModel)]="insideLookupModel"
                   (ngModelChange)="onInsideLookupChange($event)"/>
            <span mdSuffix>
                <md-icon [class.is-disabled]="disabled"
                         [style.visibility]="insideLookupModel && insideLookupModel.length > 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
                         [color]="color || 'primary'"
                         (click)="onInsideLookupClear($event)">
                    clear
                </md-icon>
            </span>
        </md-input-container>
        <a *ngIf="typeAheadMessage && typeAheadMessage.length > 0"
           search-status-message
           md-list-item>
            <span>
                {{typeAheadMessage}}
            </span>
        </a>
    </blu-type-ahead-selection-list>
</ng-template>
```

> So the [(ngModel)] for different inputs is bound to the value, and the
>   get is called multiple times if CD is set to normal CD, my question
>   was is this normal in the framework, cause I thought that this might
>   trigger some performance issues at some point.

Comment: This is probably every time change detection is run. You can try to set `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and check if it reduces the number of calls.

Comment: I suppose this is true. This is the expected behavior ?Cause for example I thaught that this is caled so many times because when I return the value from the get I trigger another change detection to run and it gets called again

Comment: I would need to see how exactly you use it in your code but I assume it's the expected behavior.

Comment: @Nicu I feel like you don't need to actually implement `ControlValueAccessor`. Take a look at [the directives ending in _value_accessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/4.1.3/packages/forms/src/directives). This interface is implemented by directives to create a bridge between Angular and native elements. Eg: exposing native elements events as Angular outputs. Can you explain the purpose of your implementation? I think there can be a better way of achieving what you need.

Comment: @Nicu for example, if you have a value in your component which changes, then you can use an `Observable` or a `Subject` if you need to manipulate it directly. Then you have all the flexibility, change it, subscribe to it, and lots of operators that can be used on it, lots of flexibility. And you have also the `async` pipe if you need to bind the observable to your template.

Comment: `ControlValueAccessor` is to make custom components act like Angular form components that work with `ngModel` and model driven forms

Comment: Right now I use this only for reactive forms and to have a common way to implemeny value accessor I created this class and each component used in reactive forms implements this method I was just warried because I had only a Type ahead component in a form and that form triggered valueChanges quite often and it took some time to find the problem, during that problem solving I noticed how often is called the get value () and I thaught that might trigger normal cd to run multiple times :D that was the reason for the question

Comment: I will update the question with the type ahead component, and it's template

Comment: Your getter `get value` will be executed on every tick. Its expected behavior

Comment: Ok thanks for answer.